# How can we argue that any binary number plus $1$ is a binary number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, binary

I am working with the definition of a binary number $n$ to be $$
n=c_k \cdot 2^k+c_{k-1} \cdot 2^{k-1}+\cdots+c_1 \cdot 2^1+c_0 \cdot 2^0
$$
where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c_i \in\{0,1\}$ for all $i \leq k$.

I am working on a strong inductive proof that every natural number has a binary representation which uses the argument that a binary number $+1$ is a binary number. I have tried to justify this by saying that when we add $2^0$ to $n$, it will keep combining with terms until eventually a coefficient of a power of $2$ is $0$, and this number "settles in" to the sum defined to be a binary number (as if there is a $1 \cdot 2^0$ in the sum given in the definition, adding $2^0$ will get $2^1$, which in turn could combine with a $2^1 $ to produce a $2^2$, etc.).
However, this argument is very informal and I am not sure if it is valid due to not being able to formalize it. How could we argue that a binary number $+1$ is a binary number?`

Comment: You can use the same argument that says a decimal number plus one is a decimal number.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use **strong** induction rather than simple induction, you don't need to worry about $+1$.  Instead, assume that **every** positive integer $< n$ is a binary number $c_k 2^k + \ldots + c_0$ with $c_k = 1$.  Let $k$ be the greatest integer such that $n \ge 2^k$ (use another induction to show that such $k$ exists).  If
$n = 2^k$, then that is a binary number with $c_i = 0$ for $i < k$ and $c_k = 1$.
Otherwise, $m = n - 2^k$ is a positive integer $< n$ so by the induction hypothesis
it is a binary number $c^j 2^j + \ldots + c_0$ with $c_j = 1$.  Since $n < 2^{k+1} $,
$m = n - 2^k <  2^k$, and $j < k$.  Then $n = 2^k + c_j 2^j + \ldots + c_0$ is a binary number.

Comment: How can I justify using only $n=1$ for the base case for this strong inductive argument? Somehow, it doesn't "feel" right to me, but it seems this argument would work for all $n$ for which there is a power of 2 less than it,  so $1$ need be the only base case as everything else can be explained by the inductive step. Is there a better way to argue why $n=1$ can  be the only base case?

Answer (score 1):

If you really intend to prove things in a very formal way, you can prove that for $n = c_k 2^k + \cdots + c_0 2^0$, if you take
$$i := \min \{ j | c_j = 0 \}$$
you have if $i \neq k$
$$n+1 = c_k 2^k + \cdots + c_i 2^i$$
And if $i = k$:
$$n+1 = c_{k+1} 2^{k+1} $$

But it is not really mandatory if you get how adding $1$ works.